# Can you add a function to a mode-hook to resize the window that the mode opens?

Tags: haskell, emacs, elisp, haskell-mode

In haskell-mode, `C-c C-b` opens a GHC REPL for testing and whatnot. However, it invariably opens in a frame equal in size to the one in which I am coding. There is a mode hook, `inferior-haskell-mode-hook`, but my attempts to add something along the lines of

```
(add-hook 'inferior-haskell-mode-hook 
    (lambda () (shrink-window 4)))
```

have resulted in either no effect, or the error message `Cannot resize the root window of a frame`. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The newest update to haskell-mode has borked the REPL functionality entirely, so this question is moot, or at least I can't test the answers until I fix it...

Comment: Why not just use `C-'` or the `haskell-interactive-bring` function ?

Comment: Have you considered just using a split window instead of a new frame?

Answer (score 1):

Your error says it all, you cannot resize a window if it is the only window in a frame, it doesn't make sense to do so.

If what you want is to actually change the frame height, just use `set-frame-height`, you could use it in conjunction with `frame-height` to shrink the frame by 4 lines.

```lisp
(set-frame-height (current-frame) (- (frame-height (current-frame)) 4)
```

It could be the case you are not always creating a new frame, in which case you could check if you should actually shrink the window by checking if `(window-size-fixed-p (current-window) nil)` is 1. Then do `shrink-window` else shrink the frame.

Answer (score 1):

As @Jordan said, you can explicitly specify the size of the frame that is created.

In addition, to fit a frame to the buffer shown in its (typically sole) window, you can use library [`fit-frame.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/fit-frame.el).  I bind it to `C-x C-_`.  And if you also use library [`autofit-frame.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/autofit-frame.el) then you can have frames automatically fit to their buffers.

For example, if `C-c C-b` creates a frame that shows a buffer that is already filled with text (I have no idea whether that is the case), then `autofit-frame.el` can be used to have the new frame automatically shrink-fit the buffer.

Of if not - if the new frame essentially shows an empty buffer (e.g. for testing) and you want a larger frame for what you will type into it, you can forego automatic fitting and fit the frame manually whenever you like.

Or you can put command `fit-frame` on a hook, to fit the frame to its buffer according to some state or event.

[More info](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Shrink-Wrapping_Frames).